# Adapters for WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I just recently installed v4.0.3. I am looking for the adapter for COTS such as SAP BAPI & IDoc, PeopleSoft, MS Navision, IBM WebSphere MQ, Oracle AQ, MSMQ and cloud services such as Salesforce, Paypal, LinkedIn, Twitter, JIRA as listed in the website. http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus

However, I can't find any. I wonder if there is a link to download all the adapters?

I would also like to ask if there is any good or similar links that teach how to integrate other cloud services such Flickr into ESB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WSO2 SAP Adapter will be available in the next public release of WSO2 ESB. Currently WSO2 offers it under development and production support subscriptions.
- Oracle AQ - Please refer [1] to a complete guide on integrating Oracle AQ with wso2.
- All MQ series integrations can be done with WSO2 ESB as it has inherent support for JMS. For instance, refer [2]
- LinkedIn, Twitter : At the moment we support these with the use of Rest API(doing RESTful invocations). However, there are some ongoing development on WSO2 API Manager, which gives out of the box experience of using these APIs. 
  -Salesforece refer [3]. Also, there are some more work going on improving OOB support for such cloud services.
- Flicker offers various APIs, so that you can use ESB to integrate with any of those API. http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

[1] http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2011/11/configuring-wso2-esb-with-oracle-as-messaging-media

[2] http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2009/09/enterprise-messaging-with-synapse-wso2.html

[3] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-7819

Comment: thank for the link. For REST API, how do I integrate it? I notice that from this link http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/rest_api_samples.html#Sample800, it only uses samples that came with the ESB. Is there any documentation that guide how to integrate API such as twitter and linkedIn?